# What uses my diskspace?

Tags: windows-8

Please forgive if this is obvious - I haven't used Windows for decades - and it's fallen on me to sort out an old laptop with Windows 8 installed. When I open 'Properties' for 'Windows (C:)', it shows that the disk is 110GB, of which 56.8GB is used.

However, when I open 'Properties' for all the folders under 'Windows (C:)', the sizes don't add up at all - they only use about 20GB. I've tried logging in as Administrator, and I've shared the disk folder, mounted it as Administrator from Linux and run `du -sh *`, and still get the same result. IS there any way in which I can see what is using all the space?

Comment: Open Windows Explorer, View, Options and be sure to set options for displaying both Hidden Files and Extensions.  Windows Defaults hide these.  For a much better and more accurate display of your files use Tree Size Pro (Jam Software).

Comment: There isn’t a equivalent to the du command on Windows

Answer (score -1):

There are probably some hidden files, like hibernation file and paging file, plus some filesystem overhead.

You can use [WizTree](https://wiztreefree.com/) to visualize what's using up space. It's better than alternatives like WinDirStat because it inspects the filesystem on a very low level. As a bonus it's much faster too.

Comment: Downvoter, please explain what's wrong with this answer and how it should be improved. Downvoting without explanation is counter-productive - either I'm mistaken, but I don't know where, or you're mistaken, but you won't learn where.

Comment: I also would like to know if that is practical (I do not downvote answers).

Comment: @John Sorry, I don't understand what you mean?

Comment: I thought your answer was fine. That is what I meant. I was not trying to be confusing.